# How to include real presents as end-of-session loot?

Tags: dnd-5e, treasure, story

I'm DMing one shot for my little sister's birthday with my family. I had the idea that at the end of the game, we can give her presents to her similarly to how I usually give players a reward at the end of a session or plot. It doesn't have to be complex, but I'd like something in the plot to involve or "cause" her getting her presents.

Basically: **How can I incorporate real presents into a session as loot and have it make (some) sense in game that the loot is her birthday presents?**

Answerers are reminded of our [Good Subjective/Bad Subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) policy. The best answers will have evidence from times they have done this and how it worked out.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! While this sounds great, this kind of idea generation question isn't a great fit for our site. We do however maintain a list of [forums](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/52137) where you may have better luck. Take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already and see the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Once you get up to 20 rep, you'll also be able to join [chat] where folks may be able to help. And you've got 20 rep now :)

Comment: I've edited the question to try to make it fit out model a little better. I think it's a good question that should have valuable answer, just needs to be slightly less idea generation.

Comment: Would there be in-game items corresponding to the actual presents? Would they be intended to have any mechanical impact in-game? (Also, would these just be given at the end of the session, in which case it might not really matter much what in-game effect they have? Do you intend to continue at all after this one-shot?)

Comment: Are you specifically looking for techinques to make a specific presents make sense? Or that her character is receiving presents in general? The more information you can give us about the session the better chance we have of answering. P.S I love this question and hope we can get it open.